# Why do quotes turn into funny characters when submitted in an HTML form?

Tags: character-encoding

I have an HTML form, and some users are copy/pasting text from MS Word. When there are single quotes or double quotes, they get translated into funny characters like:

'Â€Â™ and Ã¢Â€Â™

The database column is collation utf8_general_ci.

How do I get the appropriate characters to show up?

**Edit:**
Problem solved. Here's how I fixed it:

Ran `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` before adding/retreiving from the database. (thanks to Donal's comment below).

And somewhat odd, the php function `urlencode($text)` was applied when displaying, so that had to be removed.

I also made sure that the headers for the page and the ajax request/response were all utf8.

Comment: MS Word changes quotes into "smart quotes", which are anything but smart.  They use a Microsoft "code page" instead of Unicode.

Comment: You will notice this with some hyphens too.

Comment: If all encodings are specified correctly, these should be automatically converted to their Unicode equivalent. I doubt the problem is specific to Word; try typing e.g. Alt+130 (é) directly, and see if it comes across cleanly.

Comment: There's something strange about Ã¢Â€Â™ - it looks like it's been mangled twice - first, a right single quote sent as utf8 to a process expecting cp1252; secondly it's been converted again to utf8 by a very naive conversion that's working just on the bytes rather than looking up the Unicode database. If you're in PHP/Mysql, the first transformation might be accounted for by utf8 being saved in a database without first running "set names utf8", and the second transformation is what utf8_encode does.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This looks like a classic case of unicode (UTF-8 most likely) characters being interpreted as iso-8859-1.  There are a couple places along the way where the characters can get corrupted.  First, the client's browser has to send the data. It might corrupt the data if it can't convert the characters properly to the page's character encoding.  Then the server reads the data and decodes the bytes into characters.  If the client and server disagree about the encoding used then the characters will be corrupted.  Then the data is stored in the database; again there is potential for corruption. Finally, when the data is written on the page (for display to the browser) the browser may misinterpret the bytes if the page doesn't adequately indicate it's encoding.

You need to ensure that you are using UTF-8 throughout.  The default for web pages is iso-8859-1, so your web pages should be served with the Content-Type header or the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

(make sure you really are serving the text in that encoding).

By using UTF-8 along all parts of the process you will avoid problems with all working web browsers and databases.

Comment: +1, there's no one local fix for these problems, the important thing is the mindset of being encoding-aware wherever you're transmitting or storing text.

Answer (score 8):

Check the encoding that the page uses. Encode it using UTF-8 as well, and add a meta tag describing the encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 5):

We have a PHP function that tries to clean up the mess with smart quotes. It's a bit of a mess, since it's grown a bit organically as cases popped up during prototype development. It may be of some help, though:

```
function convert_smart_quotes($string) {
    $search = array(chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x98),
                    chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x99),
                    chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x9c),
                    chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x9d),
                    chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x93),
                    chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x94),
                    chr(226) . chr(128) . chr(153),
                    'â€™','â€œ','â€<9d>','â€"','Â  ');

     $replace = array("'","'",'"','"',' - ',' - ',"'","'",'"','"',' - ',' ');

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
```

Comment: I've done this myself, but I think it's a bad idea. If you have a text process or any other kind of process that corrupts your data, fix the process so it doesn't corrupt the data, don't just make piecemeal corrections to the output.

Comment: Yes - half a decade later.  I stumbled upon this as I was maintaining existing code.  I knew about the cut/paste issues from programs like Word, but to back up @mike-a on it, sometimes you can't control the source of the information, and you have to take a normalization approach to your data stream.  I used this, and added one more for â€¢ (first level bullets that I had).