# Mysql/php treating left/right quote differently from regular quotes, how to stop it?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble submitting form data to my mysql database.  Mysql/Php seems to be treating the open and closed quotes (a.k.a. “ and ”) differently from other characters such as your regular (") or even (<) (>) or (&).

What gets submitted to my database is &#8220 and &#8221 and I don't want that.  I want open and closed quotes to appear just like any other character.  What is odd is that if I hit the "back button" on my browser and resubmit the same post, I will get what I want submitted to my database.  But I want the (“) and (”) to submit correctly on the first try.

I haven't tested all characters to see which work and which don't, but I have tested some and it appears only the open and closed special quotes are the only ones giving trouble.

Here is my query structure:

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
$topictitle = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topictitle']);
$topiccategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topiccategory']);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = "INSERT INTO `ttable` (`topictitle`,`user`,`cat`,`postcontent`,`posttime`,`replylast`) VALUES ('".$topictitle."','".$_SESSION['user']."','".$topiccategory."','".$content."','".$date."','".$date."')";
```

My form is really long and I dont think it will be relevant so I won't post that.

Any idea what might cause this behavior?

Note: mysql_real_escape_string does not seem to be escaping the open/close quotes...

Update: Changing my method to "get" instead of "post" so I can see my view source...the $_GET['content'] view source shows the code, not the quote.  So something must be happening before I even get to the mysql query page.  I still can't see why it converts the special quote to a code.  I haven't done anything to it.

UPDATE2: I put a string_replace in right before the mysql query  and right after the mysql_real escape string.  I figured that I could at least replace all instances of &#8220 and &#8221 with left and right quotes again.  Instead, now what I get in my database is....â€œ and â€  ... so there's definitely something funny goin on...

UPDATE3: UPDATE2 was missing the fact that I put this (

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

) at the head of my page when that happened.

UPDATE4: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487369/why-do-quotes-turn-into-funny-characters-when-submitted-in-an-html-form) looks like a similar problem, but doesnt fix mine.  Putting the meta tag at the top of the pages creates a new problem where special quotes get turned into â€œ and â€ ...  I should perhaps note that I am on a mac.

Comment: `&#8220` is an HTML entity. PHP and MySQL won't do that by itself, you must be calling `htmlentities()` somewhere, perhaps when displaying the database contents.

Comment: There are no instances of the function "htmlentities" on any of the relevant pages.  There used to be, but I got rid of them.  A while ago... I thought for a moment that maybe somehow old pages got cached somehow but that's impossible.  I can visibily see through using an echo command that the pages have changed.  And anyway, why would other characters not get the same treatment?

Comment: If it's only these two characters, there's probably some code somewhere that's specifically encoding them, e.g. using `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()`, or the equivalent on the client. Have you checked whether these characters are in `$_POST['content']`?

Comment: When I check that output, say for “f”, what I get is "“f”" when I view the page source and “f” when I view the page.  (Actually, I dont know if this is relevant but I had to use Chrome's "Inspect Element" because viewing the page source made me resubmit the post content.)

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. Might I suggest learning about prepared statements using PDO or mysqli. This is the preferred way for PHP/DB interaction and would be much more useful than trying to fix your current problem.

Comment: does this deprecation potentially explain what is going on here?

Comment: @dan08 That's unlikely to be related.  As Barmar said, these look like html entities, not an encoding issue

Comment: Could it be the textarea that's doing it?  I swear there is no instance of htmlentities anywhere...

Comment: Update: Changing my method to "get" instead of "post" so I can see my view source...the $_GET['content'] view source shows the code, not the quote.  So something must be happening before I even get to the mysql query page.

Comment: Is is really a default `<textarea>`? Or was it 'taken over' by some WYSIWYG HTML JavaScript/HTML library?

Comment: Well I put in some buttons that insert bbcode into the textarea...I dont think that would have an effect.  Its just a textarea