# hyphen is converted into diamond black question mark, while setting Excel column header using apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

work book creation

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet dashboardData = workbook.createSheet("name of the excel sheet");
```

this is where I am creating the header

```
cell = row.createCell(3);
cell.setCellValue("Subscriber Count - Active");
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Comment: The question mark is a missing-character symbol: The "hyphen" is a non-ascii character (probably inserted by your text editor in place of a typed `-`), which is not available in the font you are using for display.

Comment: @alexis: '-' is needed in the header. Is there any way I can get what I have typed in cellValue?

Comment: There is an ascii hyphen character (actually it appears in your question). But it's not in your actual code. Manually type a regular hyphen into your code, look at it carefully to ensure the editor doesn't change it into something else, and it'll hopefully go ok. And/or figure out what caused the problem in the first place; you give no information about how you wrote this code (and did you copy-paste the cell header from another document?), so nobody can help you.

Comment: @alexis: Thank you so much. indeed it was copy pasted from the template. I could see the difference.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've combined my comments into an answer. Please "accept" it by clicking on the big check mark on its left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The black diamond with a question mark is a missing-character symbol: The "hyphen" in your header is a non-ascii character (probably inserted by your text editor in place of a typed "-"), which is not available in the font you are using for display. There is also an ascii hyphen character, but clearly you are not using it.

Usually this happens when a text editor (e.g., Word) replaces a typed hyphen, [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487369/why-do-quotes-turn-into-funny-characters-when-submitted-in-an-html-form), or other character with a typographically nicer but less widely available symbol. This is a well-known source of [problems](https://sph.umich.edu/computing/web/training/word.html) with online text. Sounds like you copy-pasted the offending text from elsewhere, so to fix the problem, simply edit your code in your programming editor or API and manually type in an ascii hyphen.